# Understanding Telegram iOS open source ASWatcher & ASHandle objects

Tags: ios, telegram

Thanks to Telegram open source code, I'm trying to learn a good behaviour for my apps as Telegram guys do.

Like here: http://telegram.org/resources/telegram_iphone.src.zip

Interesting 2 objects I noticed major use in objects `ASWatcher` & `ASHandle`.
I'm trying to understand what exactly it's suppose to do.
I tried to put a few logs and follow the methods.
So far what I understood is those object observe items on `UIViewController` and track changes, and return back the object and the new value from the object.

I don't know how I'm right or wrong but it looks to me a very interesting approach or objects to learn.
I'll glad to help here if someone does know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know it's too late answer But for one whom might still interested:

ASWatcher and ASHandle are implementation of **Actor Model** which is:

> A conceptual model to deal with concurrent
>   computation. It defines some general rules for how the system’s
>   components should behave and interact with each other

The most famous language that uses this model is probably **Erlang**

An actor is the primitive unit of computation. It’s the thing that receives a message and do some kind of computation based on it

The idea is very similar to what we have in object-oriented languages: An object receives a message (a method call) and does something depending on which message it receives (which method we are calling).
The main difference is that actors are completely isolated from each other and they will never share memory. It’s also worth noting that an actor can maintain a private state that can never be changed directly by another actor

It’s important to understand that, although multiple actors can run at the same time, an actor will process a given message sequentially. This means that if you send 3 messages to the same actor, it will just execute one at a time. To have these 3 messages being executed concurrently, you need to create 3 actors and send one message to each.

as you can see in telegram code in **ASHandle** :

```
- (void)reset
{
    TG_SYNCHRONIZED_BEGIN(_delegate);
    _delegate = nil;
    TG_SYNCHRONIZED_END(_delegate);
}

- (bool)hasDelegate
{
    bool result = false;

    TG_SYNCHRONIZED_BEGIN(_delegate);
    result = _delegate != nil;
    TG_SYNCHRONIZED_END(_delegate);

    return result;
}
```

Further reading : [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Actor_model) and [this](https://www.brianstorti.com/the-actor-model/)